# Как отследить очистку состояния в React.useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, useeffect

У меня есть два компонента. Они расположены на разных страницах. Они связаны между собой только тем что в компоненте 1 и 2 запрашивается один и тот же стейт tabData. Перейти в эти компоненты можно с любой другой страницы. А так же через 1 компонент можно перейти в компонент 2 и наоборот.
стейт tabData представляет собой объект:

```
tabData = {tabId: '12', startTime: '12/08/2023', ebdTime: '12/08/2023', ... }
```

в 1 компоненте данные tabData используются. Поэтому мне нужно их запросить и при размонтировании компонента удалить (в случае перехода на другую страницу, где не может быть компонента 2)

```
   useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTabData());

    return () => {
      dispatch(clearTabData());
    };
  }, []);
```

во втором компоненте мне нужно вызвать так же fetchTabData и так же его очистить при  размонтировании (так как возможен переход на другие страницы). Плюс в этом компоненте я вызываю дополнительно функцию на получение данных, которые требуют значения tabData.tabId. Поэтому я сначала вызываю fetchTabData, а затем вторым useEffect

```
const tabId= useSelector(getTabIdId);

       useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchTabData());
    
        return () => {
          dispatch(clearTabData());
        };
      }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tabId) {
      dispatch(getPassId(tabId));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [tabId]);
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  data: {},
};

export const tabSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'TAB_TAB',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTabData: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload
    },
    clearTabData: (state) => {
      state.data = initialState.data
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setTabData,
  clearTabData,
} = tabSlice.actions;

export const tabDataReducer = tabSlice.reducer;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  tabData: tabDataReducer,
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})
```

Проблема в том что при переходе с компонента 1 где очищается стейт, данные стейта еще актуальны для компонента 2. Где этот же стейт и используется.  В итоге getPassId(tabId) вызывается несколько раз. Так как tabId сначала присутствует, потом он undefined, а после чего опять со значением. Так как мы запросили заново стейт.
Получается данные не успевают очиститься при размонтировании компонента 1. Как исправить данную проблему чтобы getPassId(tabId) вызывался лишь 1 раз. При заходе на этот компонент и при переходе с компонента 1 на компонент 2

Comment: если что проверить ответ запроса getPassId  в
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tabId && (есть ли ответ на getPassId ) ) {
      dispatch(getPassId(tabId));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [tabId]);
 не работает. Не успевает получить ответ как получает то что tabId уже не сущствует